# Data set too large to load into memory for processing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a bigger rapidly growing data set of around 4 million rows, in order to define and exclude the outliers (for statistics / analytics usage) I need the algorithm to consider all entries in this data set. However this is too much data to load into memory and my system chokes. I'm currently using this to collect and process the data:

```
@scoreInnerFences = innerFence Post.where( :source => 1 ).
                                    order( :score ).
                                    pluck( :score )
```

Using the typical divide and conquer method won't work, I don't think because every entry has to be considered to keep my outlier calculation accurate. How can this be achieved efficiently?

`innerFence` identifies the lower quartile and upper quartile of the data set, then uses those findings to calculate the outliers. Here is the (yet to be refactored, non-DRY) code for this:

```
def q1(s)
  q = s.length / 4

  if s.length % 2 == 0
    return ( s[ q ] + s[ q - 1 ] ) / 2
  else
    return s[ q ]
  end
end

def q2(s)
  q = s.length / 4

  if s.length % 2 == 0
    return ( s[ q * 3 ] + s[ (q * 3) - 1 ] ) / 2
  else
    return s[ q * 3 ]
  end
end

def innerFence(s)
  q1 = q1(s)
  q2 = q2(s)

  iq = (q2 - q1) * 3

  if1 = q1 - iq
  if2 = q2 + iq

  return [if1, if2]
end
```

Comment: What does `innerFence` do? The obvious answer is to do whatever you're doing in `innerFence` in the database instead of in Ruby—but whether that's possible depends on the actual implementation of `innerFence`.

Comment: It's identifying the lower and upper quartiles of my data set and then calculating the outliers. I've added the source in my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way, but it is an easy way:

Do several querys. First you count the number of scores:

q = Post.where( :source => 1 ).count

then you do your calculations
then you fetch the scores

q1 = Post.where( :source => 1 ).
reverse_order(:score).
select("avg(score) as score").
offset(q).limit((q%2)+1)

q2 = Post.where( :source => 1 ).
reverse_order(:score).
select("avg(score) as score").
offset(q*3).limit((q%2)+1)

The code is probably wrong but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: This route worked much better and I was able to get it working by selecting my quartiles w/ offset based on the count instead of loading all the data into rails. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! You probably want to wrap it in a transaction if someone is inserting data at the same time your doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For large datasets, I sometimes drop down below ActiveRecord. It's a memory hog, even I imagine, using pluck. Of course it's less portable, but sometimes it's worth it.

scores = Post.connection.execute('select score from posts where score > 1 order by score').map(&:first)

Don't know if that will help enough for 4 million record. If not, maybe look at a stored procedure?

Comment: It is sometimes correct to skip AR but in yhis case like many others it just helps you to shoot yourself in the foot quicker. ;) This problem can be solved much simpler than loading millions of numbers into rails.